# Unicode characters not importing properly into MySQL

Tags: mysql, unicode

So heres the problem, I am trying to import a database to mysql using a sql file. The data contains unicode character data such as the "Æ" Character. Running the SQL file inserts the data as a different character "å". I can get the database to store the character correctly if I paste the insert directly into the command line. However I have 27000 inserts and I can't do it for all of them. Please help me find a way to get MySQL to accept these characters from a source file. Just for test purposes I have a file I'm running that contains

```
SELECT 'Æther';
```

Running this line on the command line works just fine.

source test.sql 
returns  'åther' when run from the command line

I would post pictures but this is my first question and it says I need reputation

Just to Clarify, my database and tables are set to use utf8mb4 utf8mb4_unicode_ci

This problems isn't that the database can't store the character, it's that its reading it incorrectly from the file.

Comment: Have you tried to import using command prompt?

Comment: make sure your client->server connection is utf as well. you have to use the SAME character set throughout, at ever stage of the pipeline, or add in appropriate translation logic.

Comment: Are you using `SET NAMES utf8mb4;` (or equivalent)?  Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...;` so we can see the hex that is stored.  I do not see how `Æ` can turn into `å`.  In utf8mb4, `Æ` is hex `C386`.